# If P tag is display:none; Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following...

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('p:contains("You")').parent('span').prev('input').addClass('error');
  });
```

My function works fine given that it adds the class to the correct inputs but it should only add the class if the paragraph containing 'you' is display:inline.

Has anybody any idea of how I can do this?

---

My markup for each input is similar to this....

```
<li class="yourdetli">
    <label class="yourdet">House Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_TB_HNumber2" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TB_HNumber2">
    <span style="color: Red; display: none;" class="errorp" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_RequiredFieldValidator9">
        <p>You must complete this field</p>
    </span>
 </li>
```

Comment: Is `visible` specific enough?

Comment: I suspect you're traversing the DOM incorrectly. Can you provide the HTML?

Comment: It seems to be working fine, but for somereason its picking up the 'p' has 'You' in the content despite the display being set to none?

Comment: Your input is invalid. You can't put a `<p>` inside a `<span>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and check the display property:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('p:contains("You")').filter(function(){
                               return $(this).css('display') === 'inline';
                               })
                               .parent('span')
                               .prev('input')
                               .addClass('error');
  });
```

filter keeps the element if the function returns true

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p:contains("You"):visible')
```

Assuming you aren't changing the display on your paragraphs anywhere in the document.

Comment: Visible is different from having `display:inline`

Comment: Yep, I'm just going off of his title.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try collecting all `<p>` tags that contain `you` and loop though all of them with a `if` statement.

If css `display` is `inline` then add `error` to `input`.

This may help

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p:contains('you')").each(function(){
    if($(this).css('display') === 'inline'){
      $(this).parent('span').prev(':input').addClass('error');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

:contains is case sensitive.  "You"
Not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf("yes") >= 0)
To also look for a sub string.